# I keep getting undefined when running .find() in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm importing an entire folder of images at the top-level:

```js
const images = require.context('./imgs', false);
const imageList = images.keys().map(image => images(image));
```

and I have a variable that contains one of the images path's. (staticImg.value)
I'm trying to match that variable with the corresponding image in the imageList:

```js
const imageItem = imageList.find(image => image.endsWith(staticImg.value.toString()));
```

but it keeps returning undefined.

this is the console log for all of them:

```js
console.log(imageList);
console.log(staticImg.value);
console.log(imageItem);
```

```
ndsectask.js:467 (4) ['/static/media/43bce663-066b-4e55-b322-8c86410c4b16.9580b3807bcba5a3d1aa.png', '/static/media/ab8d6c13-29dd-40fe-95bc-f0c6e04705c1.4f532b80fd144a86a5f0.png', '/static/media/e74cf64a-406d-49b3-a241-98b2d368d509.9ce853d8a1e419d7f38d.png', '/static/media/fe8b78fa-50f5-4061-bf09-1932fc2f0beb.9ce853d8a1e419d7f38d.png']
ndsectask.js:468 fe8b78fa-50f5-4061-bf09-1932fc2f0beb.png
ndsectask.js:469 undefined
```

What am i doing wrong here?

The aim is to get that exact image and put it in an <img src{} /> tag.

Comment: You're probably expecting it to return the last value from your `imageList` array -> `/static/media/fe8b78fa-50f5-4061-bf09-1932fc2f0beb.9ce853d8a1e419d7f38d.png`, but as you see that string doesn't end with `fe8b78fa-50f5-4061-bf09-1932fc2f0beb.png` You might need to use a split method based on a combination of `/` and `.`

Comment: `fe8b78fa-50f5-4061-bf09-1932fc2f0beb.png` does not appear at all in `imageList` ... so the result is as exepcted

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I don't need that last part or the hash. is there a way to remove it entirely?